# Docker image Package Patch within Dockerfile

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, patch

I have below docker image, where I need to update patch to curl package, in below Docker image, in Line number 3 I am already doing update, but it is shown up in Vulnerabilities report.

I have added, RUN yum -y update curl at the end of Dockerfile, then it is not showing up in Vulnerabilities report.

Any fix?, All Packages must install with latest version, I dont want to be mention explicitly

or any mistakes in Dockerfile?

```
FROM    centos:7 AS base

FROM        base AS build


# Install all dependenticies
RUN yum -y update \
    && yum install -y openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel \
                      zlib-devel wget gcc make
# Below compile python from source


FROM        base

ENV         LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64:/usr/local/lib
COPY --from=build /usr/local/ /usr/local/

# Copy Code
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app

#Install code dependecies.
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt

# Why, I need this step, when I already update RUN in line 3?, If I won't perform I see in compliance report, any fix?
RUN yum -y update curl

# run Application
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["test.py"]
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] next time. In particular, your line 3 doesn't perform any updates. In any case, what you did in `build` is irrelevant when you start a new image derived from `base`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt,  This means, I need to change yum -y update from RUN yum -y update curl, so that all packages will up to date?

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand what constitutes an image, you need to look at a Dockerfile in a different way:

- Every step (with the exception of `FROM`) creates a new image, with the results of the previous step as a base.
- `FROM` doesn't use the previous step, but an explicitly specified one.

Now, looking at your Dockerfile, you seem to wonder why `RUN yum -y update curl` doesn't work as expected. For easier understanding, let's trace it backwards:

- `RUN yum -y update curl`
- `RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip \ && pip install -r requirements.txt`
- `WORKDIR /app`
- `COPY . /app/`
- `COPY --from=build /usr/local/ /usr/local/`
- `ENV         LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64:/usr/local/lib`
- `FROM        base` -- at this point, the previous step is changed to the last step of `base`
- `FROM    centos:7 AS base` -- here, the previous step is changed to `centos:7`

As you see, nowhere in the earlier steps is `yum update -y curl`!

BTW: Typing this, I'm wondering what your precise question is, i.e. whether this works or doesn't or whether you wonder why it's necessary. Are you aware of the difference between `yum update` and `yum update curl` even?

Comment: I know the difference between yum update (all packages in the system) and yum update curl (Only curl package update), It is working too, my question is,  in Build phase, I have already updated all packages (Line 3), again after FROM Base, I am doing it again, I am checking can it be avoided?

Comment: You could do it in the image named "base". At the moment, it only contains what is in the CentOS image. That's also the usual motivation for splitting into a base image and two derived images.

Answer (score 0):

`docker build` and friends have a cache system, based on the *text* of the input. So if the text of the command `yum -y update` doesn't change, it will continue using the same cached version of the output forever (or until the cache is deleted). Try running the build with `--no-cache` and see if that helps.